# alá insight for windows

Tags: c, windows, debugging, assembly, insight

I am trying to install insight debugger on my windows 7 machine but without any success.

I installed `cygwin` full package and I downloaded the source of insight. I am following the steps in [this tutorial](http://www.gevawebsolutions.com/wiki/index.php?title=Insight_Debugging) without any success, I already spent 2 hours trying compiling, but nothing. It always gives me the same error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../include/w32api/winsock2.h:632:32:  
error: conflicting types for 'select'  
/usr/include/sys/select.h:31:5: note: previous declaration of 'select' was here  
make[2]: `***` [tclAlloc.o] Error 1  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/insight-6.1/tcl/win'  
make[1]: `***` [all] Error 2  
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/insight-6.1/tcl'  
make: `***` [all-tcl] Error 2
```

I want one debugger like insight to debug my C code linked with my developed assembly to IA-32

Comment: the gdb-6.8-2 cygwin binary package ships with insight; the newer version gdb-7.3.50-3 only includes the text-mode ui (command `gdbtui` or `gdb -tui`)

Comment: I did that and i just start receiving another error :| "damm"
Tcl_Init failed: Can't find a usable init.tcl .....

Comment: @Christoph i am missing something?

Comment: I think it "just worked" for me; I no longer have cygwin installed here (switched to MSYS some time ago), so I can't easily check what might be wrong...

Comment: @Christoph, how did you get insight to compile in Msys, I am getting errors while compiling. It will be very helpful if you can give me some description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, so, after very hours spent I think the best I can give is to *show you how*, I resolved the problem and I posted on my [github](http://github.com/goncalod/Utilities) page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying your instruction at github. It does not seem to tell me where to actually do the compilation. I see archives of already built insight,gdb, and tcl. Should I be compiling or just use the *.exe?